# Extract everything between <object></object>

Tags: php, regex

I am using CURL to download a page. Now I want to extract this from the page:

```
<object classid="clsid:67DABFBF-D0AB-41fa-9C46-CC0F21721616" width="640"
        height="303.33333333333"
        codebase="http://go.divx.com/plugin/DivXBrowserPlugin.cab"
        id="object701207571">
    <param name="autoPlay" value="false" />
    <param name="custommode" value="Stage6" />
    <param name="src" value="" />
    <param name="movieTitle" value="Titanic" />
    <param name="bannerEnabled" value="false" />
    <param name="previewImage" 
           value="http://stagevu.com/img/thumbnail/oripmqeqzrccbig.jpg" />
    <embed type="video/divx" src="" width="640" height="303.33333333333"
           autoPlay="false" custommode="Stage6" movieTitle="Titanic"
           bannerEnabled="false"
           previewImage="http://stagevu.com/img/thumbnail/oripmqeqzrccbig.jpg"
           pluginspage="http://go.divx.com/plugin/download/"
           id="embed701207571">
    </embed>
</object>
```

Please help!

Comment: I would have helped you out if you'd shown some thinkin' and tryin' if you know what I mean. there's plenty of Regex examples out there.

Answer (score 6):

This is partially in response to Owens *(because I can't put code in a comment very well)*.  That regex might not work for the object tag, basically because the opening `<object>` tag has attributes in it.  Try this one instead:

```
/(<object[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/object>)/si
```

It's case insensitive and broken into the three groupings for easy reference.  It's not 100% perfect, but should help.

Comment: > is legal in an attribute value, IIRC.

Comment: Also, this does not handle <object> nesting.

Comment: Which is why it is hard to parse HTML with a Regex.  But this will work for his attempt.

Comment: Yeah, these are the dangers of trying to use a regex, which is why I used a half-hearted match-what-he-showed approach. Any time spent attempting to bullet proof the regex is time that should have been spent learning how to use a parser.

Answer (score 4):

See [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-rege) for why this is probably the wrong thing to do.

That said you might be able to get away with something like `/(<object>.*?<\/object>)/s`.  This matches the string `"<object>"` followed by any number of characters up to the string `"</object>"`.  The `s` on the end tells `.` to match newlines (it normally doesn't).

Answer (score 3):

Using SimpleXML:

```
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$objects = $sxe->xpath('//object[@id="object701207571"]');
$object = $objects[0];

$params = $object->xpath('param');

foreach($params as $param)
{
    $attrs = $param->attributes();
    echo $attrs['name'] . ' = ' . $attrs['value'] . "\n";
}

// Get plain XML:
echo $object->asXML();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$doc = DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);
foreach($node->getElementsByTagName('object') as $object)
{
   echo $doc->saveXML($object);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this regex will match all the line breaks between the opening and closing tags and capture the entire thing in one group

```
/(<object[^>]*?>(?:[\s\S]*?)<\/object>)/gi
```

Comment: This will fail if objects are nested.

Comment: right .. but i don't think i've ever seen objects nested inside objects

Comment: It's completely legal.  I've seen it.  You can have an image object inside a video object inside a flash object, for example.